# How to insert a element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to insert a tooltip message after the below element, please let me know How do I do that. I want to add the message 'Please enter value' using Jquery.

in my DOM element I am getting only this:-

```
<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span> 
  <div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
</div>
```

But I want like this :-

```
<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span> Please enter value
  <div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: What did you do to get the current result?

Comment: You mean you want to add text inside '.k-i-warning' span tag ?

Comment: by using wrapall

Comment: At present my dom is displaying like this : <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span> 
  <div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
</div>

Comment: But I need to add one text using Jquery - <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span>Please enter value<div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have tested it in my local file and its working according to your need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode">
            <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span> 
            <div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(".k-icon").after("Please enter value.");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It will give you output like
<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode">
  <span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span> Please enter value
  <div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div>
</div>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I have tried your soluation, it did not work for me, I am still getting this output:<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span><div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>

Comment: Instead I need : <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span>Please enter value<div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>

Comment: @Kumas It should must work. Show me your output because I have tested it and its working very fine on my files.

Comment: @Kumas try this
setTimeout(function(){ $(".k-icon").after("Please enter value.");}, 3000);

replace $(".k-icon").after("Please enter value."); with the given code.

Comment: <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ $(".k-icon").after("Please enter value.");}, 3000);
        </script>

Comment: Replace my <script> tag with the given tag and tell me if its working or not

Comment: Hi , Thanks a again fo ryour response, Yes finally its working fine

Comment: My pleasure brother!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use `after` method to insert text after a particular tag in jquery

```
$(".k-i-warning").after('Please enter value');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, still I am getting same response. <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span><div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>

Comment: Can you write this js code inside after document  load method $(document).load(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

Hi `after` method is working and try this also `insertAfter` method

```
$( "<span>Please enter value</span>" ).insertAfter( ".k-i-warning" );
```

Comment: Thanks sam for your response, But still it did not work, I am getting as it is no update, this is the result:<div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span><div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>

Comment: Instead I need : <div class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation k-invalid-msg" role="alert" style="margin: 0.5em; display: block;" data-for="ContactPhoneCountryCode"><span class="k-icon k-i-warning"> </span>Please enter value<div class="k-callout k-callout-n"></div></div>